# Turn a php array into comma separated array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am getting data from a row which are a bunch of integers and I need to comma separate them to use them for a chart.js dataset data. So I have got the array here:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  $categories = [];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories[] = $row;     
  }

echo json_encode($categories);
```

I need to turn it into json encoded string:

My array echos out as:

```
[{"respondent_sdo":"2","respondent_dcto":"3","respondent_ed":"5","respondent_ca":"5","respondent_dhpt":"3","respondent_irt":"6","respondent_gl":"2","respondent_il":"5"}]
```

To which I need the above to output as `2,3,5,5,3,6,5`

```
var dataString= "<?php echo json_encode($categories, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);  ?>";
var catData = JSON.parse(dataString);


    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart1");
    var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'radar',
        options: {
             legend: {
                display: true
             },
             tooltips: {
                enabled: false
             },
            scale: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stepSize: 1
                }
            }         
        },  
      data: {
        labels: ["Strategic Development and Ownership", 
                 "Driving change through others", 
                 "Exec Acumen", 
                 "Commercial Acumen", 
                 "Develops High Performance Teams", 
                 "Innovation and risk taking", 
                 "Global Leadership", 
                 "Industry Leader"
                 ],


        datasets: [{
          label: 'Ian Galbraith',
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,6255,255,0)",
          borderColor: "lightblue",
          data: catData,
        }]
      }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried json_encode($array)?

Comment: Does what im doing above not do that already?

Comment: I get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` I have updated my question so its a little clearer

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Im going to guess I need to unset the key? Im a little confused at this point though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you change associative array into numeric one in PHP file like:

Instead of:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  $categories = [];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories[] = $row;     
  }

echo json_encode($categories);
```

Use:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  $categories = [];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories[] = $row;     
  }
$response = array();
foreach($categories as $c){
   foreach($c as $val){
      $response[] = (int)$val;
   }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, so it still echos out the same response so with the keys, essentially I want to turn the output into an array of just integers and no eys so I can use it for my chart above.

Comment: so it still outputs as `[{"respondent_sdo":"2","respondent_dcto":"3","respondent_ed":"5","respondent_ca":"5","respondent_dhpt":"3","respondent_irt":"6","respondent_gl":"2","respondent_il":"5"}]`

Comment: What I get it this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Can you please put `var_dump($categories)` in your PHP file before `echo json_encode($categories);` and tell me what it outputs?

Comment: I ger this... `array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["respondent_sdo"]=> string(1) "2" ["respondent_dcto"]=> string(1) "3" ["respondent_ed"]=> string(1) "5" ["respondent_ca"]=> string(1) "5" ["respondent_dhpt"]=> string(1) "3" ["respondent_irt"]=> string(1) "6" ["respondent_gl"]=> string(1) "2" } }`

Comment: So its a 2D array, you need a nested foreach to extract all content, please try the modified solution. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ok its pretty much there, it just seems to be an integer behind so in the database the first value is 3 and its showing as 2 in the output etc..

Comment: So its almost like its counting up from 0 where as it should be from 1

Comment: Its alost outputting 7 numbers where it should be 8...?

Comment: Can you post the output what you are getting from PHP file? like: `var_dump($response);` in PHP file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128696/discussion-between-dan-and-abhay-maurya).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use `Object.keys` to get the keys from the object and then populate an array with the values from those keys:

```js
// Use this in production
//var arr = <?php echo json_encode($categories, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);  ?>;

// For this example:
var arr = [{
  "respondent_sdo": "2",
  "respondent_dcto": "3",
  "respondent_ed": "5",
  "respondent_ca": "5",
  "respondent_dhpt": "3",
  "respondent_irt": "6",
  "respondent_gl": "2",
  "respondent_il": "5"
}]

var catData = [];
Object.keys(arr[0]).forEach(function(key) {
  catData.push(parseInt(arr[0][key], 10));
});

console.log(catData);
```

However, I would suggest that you instead perform the logic to extract the integers in your PHP code and just provide them to the JS.

Comment: But I cant use hard values, I need to be getting them from the database..?

Comment: Well, yes. I only put the output in here to give you an example. You need to `echo` the output from the PHP as you are now

Comment: Im super confused now, iv been thrown off the scent completely, so how would I get to the point in your example?

Comment: So I just did that and it still tells me I have the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` so its almost like the key is getting in the way of the output

Comment: To be honest that sounds like you have an error somewhere else in your code. If you click/double click the error it should show you the offending line of code (assuming it's a JS problem, not PHP)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128690/discussion-between-dan-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 1):

Or use array map function.

```
var catData = JSON.parse(dataString);
var values ='';
values += catData.map(function(a) {
    return a.foo+',';
});

values = values.replace(/,\s*$/, ""); //to remove last coma
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the example, can you advise to me where I am likely to be using this in my code snippet in my question?